# Azure API Management OAuth2 Redirect Uri is null

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I am trying to add an OAuth2 service to my Azure Api Management service (consumption plan) but the Authorization code grant flow redirect uri is being set to `null/signin-oauth/code/callback/{name}`

On the "Add OAuth2 service" tab I set the name and id of the oauth2 service (in this example its "test1")

[image]

The auto generated redirect uri is then set to `null/signin-oauth/code/callback/test1`

[image]

I know what the redirect uri should be - `https://{my-api-management-service-name}.developer.azure-api.net/signin-oauth/code/callback/test1`. When calling this I get a server not found error. So it looks like it's not being set up.

It seems to work on anything other than the consumption plan.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was following the wrong guide.

I was using the [Protect a web API backend in Azure API Management by using OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) when I should have been using the [Protect SPA backend with OAuth 2.0, Azure Active Directory B2C and Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-protect-backend-frontend-azure-ad-b2c)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to test your API in Azure Developer Portal using the console, Well, the consumption Tier does not fit and **null/** means you don't have a domain name to access the portal. So better use one of these as Tier when creating your APIM instance: Developer, Standard or Premium. Apart from that, you will have two redirects url when you create your OAuth2.0 server ***(Developer portal and Developer portal deprecated)***, configure both of them in your registered client application.

**OAuth2.0 Server**

[image]

**Client App**

[image]